# probability of multiple car ownership for a household

Tags: probability

Given that out of $100$ houses in a locality, $20$ have no car, $40$ have one car, $10$ have $2$ cars, and $30$ have $3$ cars. For a randomly selected car on the street, what is the probability that that car's household owns at least one more car.

Edit*
This isn't a homework problem. I came across the problem while going through probability questions that were asked for a junior statistician role.

My logic so far has been this.

1. $80$ houses have cars, of which $40$ have more than one. Therefore for a car to be a part of a household with multiple cars, it would be $\dfrac{40}{80} = 50$%.
2. That being said, I have $90+20= 110$ cars being from houses with more than one car; and $40$ cars from households with only one car.
   I'm not sure how to factor this into my calculations. Would the probability I am looking for, be just $\dfrac{110}{150}$? Or would it be conditioned on the probability from (1)? Or am I just looking at things the wrong way.

Its been a while since I've had to work on these sort of problems.
Thank you for any additional insight.

Comment: this is clearly a homework problem. so please 1) be clear about that, 2) mention what you have tried, and 3) mention what you know about how to solve such problems.

Comment: I think your question should be more than one car.

Comment: @TheCount I've edited the post. please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Much nicer. Always nice when people are willing to help beef things up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your point 2 is correct.  You are randomly picking a car and asking what kind of house it belongs to, not picking a house and asking what cars they have.  Your point 1 would be correct if you picked a house that was guaranteed to have at least one car and asked if they had more than one.  These are two different questions which have different answers.  In many probability problems, the important thing is to understand what question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to think about this in terms of the set of cars you have. As stated in your original post, you have a total of 150 cars. Out of these 150 cars, 90 belong to a household with 3 cars $ (30 \times 3) $, 20 belong to a household with 2 cars $ (10 \times 2) $, and 40 belong to a household with 1 car $ (1 \times 40) $.

Now you are randomly drawing from this set of 150 cars.

P(car belongs to household with 3 cars) $ = \frac{90}{150} $

P(car belongs to household with 2 cars) $ = \frac{20}{150} $

P(car belongs to household with 1 car) $ = \frac{40}{150} $